# Can I force trailing slash on URLs without using a redirect in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I have a website which has around 1,600 links without the trailing slash / at the end of the URL, these currently get redirected with a 301 redirect to the URL with the trailing slash.

But, this means my website reports around 1,600 301'd pages, so I want to manually add the trailing slash to all of those URLs in the wordpress website, so that rather than 301 redirecting any links that don't have the trailing slash, the trailing slash is added directly onto the link itself in the wordpress page, so a 301 is not necessary.

Is there a quick and easy way to do this, or am I looking at manually updating 1,600+ links throughout the website?